# Scrapy : Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)

Tags: scrapy

I am able to obtain an URL via

```
website =
pageForDetails.xpath('.//*[@id="akp_uid_8"]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/@href').extract_first()
```

An example result is

```
In [54]: website
Out[54]: 'http://www.rrhotel.is/'
```

When I try to request the URL via

```
yield Request(website,callback=self.parse_result,
                          meta={'name':name,
                                'website':website})
```

I receive an error as follows

```
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 52, in _set_url
    raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)
TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType:
2017-11-17 00:47:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

What could be the reason of the error and how can I get rid of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please log the value on `website`, chances are that you're not able to extract the url, that xpath seems to me very fragile, where are you extracting it from?

Comment: Alright, Request didn't work but I used Selenium's get() as a workaround. It worked fine :) The strange thing is that it is the same URL. Anyways, thanks for quick replies folks.